# Get file size in IE before uploading. Gmail does it - how?

Tags: javascript, forms, client-side-validation

I have a file upload form. I'd like to validate the file size before actually uploading the file. I can do this in Chrome, but how do I get it to work in IE?

Note that this is possible for gmail to do. When I drag a file into the file attachment area, then it immediately tells me the size of the file. I've tried this in IE9 and IE8. It's also able to tell me the file size even if I'm disconnected from the internet so it's not like it's uploading the file first. I've not (as far as I recall) had to give any special activeX permissions or anything.

I've seen the below in other answers, but that requires the user to give special permission, right? I'd like to avoid that. Also, I'm not sure how to actually get at the file that I need for this to work.

```
   var oas = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
   var e = oas.getFile(file.value);
```

Comment: What makes you think this needs a special permission?

Comment: What I know is that IE does not support the HTML5 File API, which allows that on other browsers. Maybe Google is using Flash on IE?

Comment: @jan: The first line above gives me an error:  "Automation server can't create object" I thought this had to do with permissions. And what I've read about activeX stuff. Do you not think so?

Comment: Yes, they must be using Flash. I just tried: Gmail could not tell me the file size when I disabled flash.

Answer (score 2):

google does it with a fallback.

if there is no html5 file api it uses adobe flash for uploading files.

you could use something like this to get crossbrowser compatiblity: https://github.com/valums/file-uploader

Comment: You're right about Flash. If I disable flash then it's not able to tell me the file size.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `ActiveXObject`, the correct code is:

```
var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject"),
    file = fso.GetFile(file_path),
    size = file.size;
```